# How cadence can save actions history?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

My case is to approve, reject or return my request, and based on that workflow should change its status.
How candence can help here to save/retrieve all actions history for each workflow.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case? What does "reject or return my request" mean? What is request and how does it relate to the worklfow?

Comment: My use case is a simple business process. Once user submit a request, then that request goes to 1st approval to take an action (approve, reject or return) based on the request data, if he approved then the request goes to 2nd approval and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow is code, so if you want to return the history of actions you would store them in a list variable and return it when queried.

As all workflow variables are persisted by the Temporal service there is no need to save them to a DB explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will be in the memory for ever! or can cadence save it to DB?

Comment: How can I configure (or ask) cadence to save them in its DB? @maxim-fateev